# In pytest, how to run against different ip for cases with different marks or name patterns

Tags: pytest

I have a question here.
I am using Pytest.
I have two cases with mark and name as:

1)

```
@pytest.mark.ip1
def test_ip1_actions()
    ...
```

2. @pytest.mark.ip2
   def test_ip2_actions()
   ...

what I want is:

if the mark is `ip1`, then I will run the test against 1st ip - `192.168.2.23`; if the mark is `ip2`, then the case should run against 2nd ip - `192.168.2.100`

or:

based on the name, if case name contains "ip1", it will run against 1st ip; if case name contains "ip2", then run against 2nd ip.

In fact I have many cases to run against 2 ips, not only 2. and the ip information (as well some other information of the two hosts) are written in an json file. So I would like to find out a general and simple solution.

I tried but didn't get it.

I thought maybe do something in the `conftest.py` file? for example, before the case running, judge the mark or the name? But don't know how to handle.

Looking forward to your advice, to my first question in stackoverflow! :)

thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

Don't quite understand, and it's hard to understand more without seeing an example test, but how about using parameters to determine which ips are passed in.

Say you have a test to check ips are accessible. This would be one way to do it, but it's not very nice or extensible.

```py
def test_ip_accessible():
    assert is_accessible("192.168.2.23")
    assert is_accessible("192.168.2.100")
```

Instead you can create helper functions that return specific ips, or a list of ips, and then use these as parameters.

```py
ip_map: Dict[int, str] = {  # ip id to address
    1: "192.168.2.23",
    2: "192.168.2.100",
    3: "192.168.2.254",
}

def get_single_ip(id_: int) -> str:
    return ip_map[id_]

def get_multiple_ips(*ids) -> Tuple[str]:
    return tuple(ip_map[i] for i in ids)


@pytest.mark.parametrize("ip_address", [get_single_ip(1), get_single_ip(2)])
def test_ip_accessible(ip_address):
    # ip_address will be 192.168.2.23 then 192.168.2.100 in two separate tests
    assert is_accessible(ip_address)


@pytest.mark.parametrize("ip_addresses", [get_multiple_ips(1, 2), get_multiple_ips(2, 3)])
def test_with_multiple_ips(ip_addresses):
    # this test will also be run twice. the first time, ip_addresses will be
    # ["192.162.2.23", "192.168.2.100"]. the second time, it will be
    # ["192.168.2.100", "192.168.2.254"].
    assert something_with_a_list_of_ips(ip_addresses)
```